# create a link to open a pdf in the navigateur with asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

I work a project with asp.net mvc2 (c sharp ).I want to create a link to open a pdf in the navigateur, the path of the pdf exixte in my data base .

Answer (score 0):

You could design a controller action which will fetch the pdf path from the database and stream it to the response:

```
public ActionResult ShowPdf()
{
    string path = ... fetch path from database
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        // the file was not found
        throw new HttpException(404, "Not found");
    }
    return File(path, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
}
```

and then you could create a link to this action in your view:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("download pdf", "showpdf", "somecontroller") %>
```

Comment: thankx a lot , this allow to download the pdf  but a want to show the pdf in my navigateur

Comment: @fatma to do that the file path that exists in your Database must be relative path not phyiscal path and assign that path to `href` of your link